# Add all the dates (week) between two dates in new Row in spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

convert spark data-frame

```
+----+---------+------+
|name|date     |amount|
+----+---------+------+
|Jhon|4/6/2018 |  100 |
|Jhon|4/6/2018 |  200 |
+----+---------+------+
|Jhon|4/13/2018|   300|
+----+---------+------+
|Jhon|4/20/2018 |  500|
+----+---------+------+
|Lee |5/4/2018 |  100 |
+----+---------+------+
|Lee |4/4/2018 |  200 |
+----+---------+------+
|Lee |5/4/2018 |  300 |
+----+---------+------+
|Lee |4/11/2018 |  700|
+----+---------+------+
```

To Expected Data-frame:

```
+----+---------+------+
|name|date     |amount|
+----+---------+------+
|Jhon|4/6/2018 |  100 |
|Jhon|4/6/2018 |  200 |
+----+---------+------+
|Jhon|4/13/2018|   100|
+----+---------+------+
|Jhon|4/13/2018|   200|
+----+---------+------+
|Jhon|4/13/2018|   300|
+----+---------+------+
|Jhon|4/20/2018 |  100 |
+----+---------+------+
|Jhon|4/20/2018 |  200|
+----+---------+------+
|Jhon|4/20/2018|   300|
+----+---------+------+
|Jhon|4/20/2018 |  500|
+----+---------+------+
|Lee |5/4/2018 |  100 |
+----+---------+------+
|Lee |5/4/2018 |  200 |
+----+---------+------+
|Lee |5/4/2018 |  300 |
+----+---------+------|
|Lee |5/11/2018 |  100|
+----+---------+------+
|Lee |4/11/2018 |  200|
+----+---------+------+
|Lee |5/11/2018 |  300|
+----+---------+------+
|Lee |4/11/2018 |  700|
+----+---------+------+
```

So here 300 is the new value for `04/13/2018` and 100,200 from `04/06/2018` will also shown for `04/13/2018`, similarly for next Friday dates for distinct names. Do we have any way to do this in Spark Scala.
 Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My code is working for only name 'John' and only foFridayfriday date `'4/6/2018'` and `4/13/2018`

```
def main(args: Array[String]){
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Excel-read-write").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlc = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val ss = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("Excel-read-write").getOrCreate()
    import ss.sqlContext.implicits._
    var df1 = sqlc.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
             .option("header", "true")
             .option("inferSchema", "true")
             .load("oldRecords.csv")
    df1.show(false)
    println("---- df1 row count ----"+df1.count())
    if(df1.count()>0){
      for (i <- 0 until (df1.count().toInt)-1) {
        var df2 = df1.unionAll(df1)//.union(df1)//df3
        //df2.show(false)
        var w1 = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy("date")
        var df3 = df2.withColumn("previousAmount",  lag("amount",1).over(w1)).withColumn("newdate", lag("date",1).over(w1))
        // df3.show(false)
        var df4 = df3.filter((df3.col("newdate").isNotNull))//(df3.col("new_date").isNotNull)
        //df4.show(false)
        var df5 = df4.select("name","amount","newdate").distinct() 
        println("-----------"+df5.show(false))
        df1 = df5.withColumnRenamed("newdate", "date")
      }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I have a scenario like below. can anyone please provide some logic.

I have the below spark Dataframe. i tried doing this using union with lag and lead function but its not giving the expected result.
 I'm just not getting any clue how to implement the solution for this.

Comment: so here 300 is the new value for 04/13/2018 and 100,200 from 04/06/2018 will also shown for 04/13/2018, similarly for next Friday dates for distinct names. Do we have any way to do this in Spark Scala. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

my code is working for only name 'John' and only for two friday date '4/6/2018' and 4/13/2018

Comment: Can you add the description in question and not in the comment ?

Comment: it not accepting in question , creating some error

Comment: my code is working only for+----+---------+------+
|name|date     |amount|
+----+---------+------+
|Jhon|4/6/2018 |  100 |
|Jhon|4/6/2018 |  200 |
+----+---------+------+
|Jhon|4/13/2018|   300|
+----+---------+------+

Comment: can you verify for the name `lee` if the expected output is right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question, If you are trying to add all the `week` to the highest date of that `name`. Here is what you can do.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.joda.time.LocalDate
// input data 
val dataDF  = Seq(
  ("Jhon", "4/6/2018", 100),
  ("Jhon", "4/6/2018", 200),
  ("Jhon", "4/13/2018", 300),
  ("Jhon", "4/20/2018", 500),
  ("Lee", "5/4/2018", 100),
  ("Lee", "4/4/2018", 200),
  ("Lee", "5/4/2018", 300),
  ("Lee", "4/11/2018", 700)
).toDF("name", "date", "amount")
  .withColumn("date", to_date($"date", "MM/dd/yyyy"))

val window = Window.partitionBy($"name")

//find the maximum date of each name
val df = dataDF.withColumn("maxDate", max($"date").over(window))
```

Create a `UDF` to find all weeks between two weeks

```
val calculateDate = udf((min: String, max: String) => {
  // to collect all the dates
  val totalDates = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[LocalDate]()
  var start = LocalDate.parse(min)
  val end = LocalDate.parse(max)
  while ( {
    !start.isAfter(end)
  }) {
    totalDates += start
    start = start.plusWeeks(1)
  }
  totalDates.map(_.toString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
})
```

Now apply the `UDF`  and `explode` the obtained `array` from `UDF`

```
val finalDf = df.withColumn("date", explode(calculateDate($"date", $"maxDate")))
                .drop("maxDate")
```

Output:

```
+----+----------+------+
|name|date      |amount|
+----+----------+------+
|Jhon|04/06/2018|100   |
|Jhon|04/13/2018|100   |
|Jhon|04/20/2018|100   |
|Jhon|04/06/2018|200   |
|Jhon|04/13/2018|200   |
|Jhon|04/20/2018|200   |
|Jhon|04/13/2018|300   |
|Jhon|04/20/2018|300   |
|Jhon|04/20/2018|500   |
|Lee |05/04/2018|100   |
|Lee |04/04/2018|200   |
|Lee |04/11/2018|200   |
|Lee |04/18/2018|200   |
|Lee |04/25/2018|200   |
|Lee |05/02/2018|200   |
|Lee |05/04/2018|300   |
|Lee |04/11/2018|700   |
|Lee |04/18/2018|700   |
|Lee |04/25/2018|700   |
|Lee |05/02/2018|700   |
+----+----------+------+
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: and why is that?

Comment: hi , due to start = start.plusWeeks(1)

Comment: I could notget the logic behind it.

Comment: solved , by left join with input df and last one and filtered by not null

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.incedo.pharma
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lag
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_date
import org.joda.time.LocalDate
object appendPreRowGeneral4 {
   def main(args: Array[String]){
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Excel-read-write").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlc = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val ss = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("Excel-read-write").getOrCreate()
    import ss.sqlContext.implicits._
    val df1 = sqlc.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
             .option("header", "true")
             .option("inferSchema", "true")
             .load("oldRecords2.csv")
    println(df1.show(false)+"df1 ---------")
    val df2 = df1.withColumn("date", to_date(unix_timestamp($"date", "MM/dd/yyyy").cast("timestamp")))
    println("df2---"+df2.show(false))
    val window1 = Window.partitionBy($"name")
    val df3 = df2.withColumn("maxDate", max($"date").over(window1))
    println(df3.show(false)+"df3 ---------")
    val df4 = df3.withColumn("newdate1", findDate($"date", $"maxDate")).drop("date")
    println("df4---"+df4.show(false))
    val df5 = df4.withColumn("date", explode($"newdate1"))
    println("df5 -----"+df5.show(false))
    val df6 = df5.drop("maxDate","newdate1")
    println("df6 -----"+df6.show(false))
    val df7 = df6.alias("a").join(df2.alias("b"),$"a.date" === $"b.date","left_outer")
              .select($"a.name",$"a.amount",$"a.date" , ($"b.name").alias("rt_name"),($"b.amount").alias("rt_amount"),($"b.date").alias("rt_date"))
    println("df7----"+df7.show(false))
    val df8 = df7.filter(df7.col("rt_date").isNotNull).select($"name", $"date", $"amount").distinct().orderBy($"name", $"date")
    println("df8----"+df8.show(false))
    val df9 = df8.withColumn("date",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"date", "yyyy-mm-dd"), "mm/dd/yyyy"))
    println("df9 ---"+df9.show(df9.count().toInt,false))
    println("total count --->"+df9.count())
   }

    val findDate = udf((first: String, last: String) => {
      // to collect all the dates
      val arrayDates = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[LocalDate]()
      var mindate = LocalDate.parse(first)
      println("mindate -----"+mindate)
      val enddate = LocalDate.parse(last)
      println("enddate -----"+enddate)
      println("boolean ----"+mindate.isAfter(enddate))
      while ( {
        !mindate.isAfter(enddate)
      }) {
        arrayDates += mindate
        println("arrayDates --->"+arrayDates)
        mindate = mindate.plusWeeks(1)
        println("mindate inside ---"+mindate)
        //start.plusMonths(1)
      }
      arrayDates.map(_.toString())//arrayDates.map(_.toString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
  })
  /**val convertDateUDF = udf((indate: String) => {
    var ret = indate
    s"${ret}"
  })*/
}
```

Comment: Hi Shankar sir, please see below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51062728/apply-validation-with-some-columns-for-following-data-frames-in-spark-sql